# What is different between isset() and !empty

Tags: php

I want to know what is different between `isset()` and `!empty`?

I know that `isset()` tests if a variable is set and not null, while
`empty()` can return true when the variable is set to certain values.

But logically when `isset()` which doesn't empty (without using "empty()"), there is a variable in text or textarea whatever so we don't need `empty()`.

Comment: foo = "" will make isset() return true, but !empty will return false. The variable foo is set to nothing, but it is still set. It has no content so !empty will return false.

Comment: I would also point you to the PHP documentation for these functions.  They should be pretty clear around how different variable type/values respond to each function.

Comment: this code is quite tricky `<? $a = 0;

if(empty($a)){
echo"EMPTY";
}

if(isset($a)){
echo"EMPTY";
}

?>` Variable a is set but it is empty in a way that empty sees. You may test such thing with a regex "^$" (empty).

Answer (score 2):

`isset` method checks if a variable exists or not. On the other hand `!empty` knows that a variable exists but it needs to check its value.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite small, but significant enough to not make mistakes with both statements. When you declare a variable like this:

```
<?php
    foo = "";
?>
```

You will end up with different values depending on what you use. `isset()` will return true, as the variable foo was set to nothing. However `!empty` will return false, as the variable foo does not contain anything. Basically `isset()` only checks for *NULL* values, where `!empty` checks for for everything that is considered 0 (so NULL, 0, 0.0 etc. but also 0 as a string, for example).